# Как сделать `zoom` картинки в самой картинке

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Как сделать `zoom` картинки в самой картинке как сделано вот [тут](http://shop.faberlic.com/component/catalog/?view=goods&id=1000207539118).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эту вещь используют: Elevate Zoom
http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples
Смотреть следует пример: Inner Zoom